# could not install frama-c-Phosphorus using opam

Tags: frama-c, opam

I had successfully installed frama-c-Silicon using opam by the instructions, but when I want to upgrade to Phosphorus, opam does not work.

I used the command:

> opam pin add frama-c Downloads/frama-c-Phosphorus20170501.tar.gz

it said that:

```
[NOTE] Package frama-c is already path-pinned to
       /home/talos/Downloads/frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501.tar.gz.
       This will erase any previous custom definition.
Proceed ? [Y/n] y

[frama-c] /home/talos/Downloads/frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501.tar.gz synchronized

frama-c needs to be installed.
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install frama-c-base 20161101*           [required by frama-c]
       Why3 can be used by the WP plug-in for running additional automatic solvers
       Coq can be used with the WP plug-in for proving interactively proof obligations
  ∗  install frama-c      20161101*
       Alt-Ergo Graphical Interface can be used by the WP plug-in
===== ∗  2 =====
Do you want to continue ? [Y/n] y

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[frama-c.20161101] /home/talos/Downloads/frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501.tar.gz already up-to-date
[frama-c-base.20161101] /home/talos/Downloads/frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501.tar.gz already up-to-date

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

#=== ERROR while installing frama-c-base.20161101 =============================#
These patches didn't apply at /home/talos/.opam/system/build/frama-c-base.20161101:
  - 4.05-support.patch



=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The following actions were aborted
  ∗  install frama-c 20161101
The following actions failed
  ∗  install frama-c-base 20161101
No changes have been performed
[NOTE] Pinning command successful, but your installed packages may be out of
       sync.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is related more to the usage of OPAM itself (`opam pin` in particular) than Frama-C.

This line in particular indicates that you have `pin`ned a Frama-C package in your OPAM installation:

```
[NOTE] Package frama-c is already path-pinned to
       /home/talos/Downloads/frama-c-Phosphorus-20170501.tar.gz.
       This will erase any previous custom definition.
```

This was only necessary before the Phosphorus package was available in OPAM. You should revert to a default configuration by removing it and then installing it via the "standard" (non-pinned) way:

```
opam pin remove frama-c
# just in case, you may want to unpin the frama-c-base package, if it is pinned
opam pin remove frama-c-base
# then install the package normally; you may need to update OPAM to make
# sure the package is available in your repository
opam update
opam install frama-c
```

Note that, if you **still** have a message displayed such as:

```
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install frama-c-base 20161101*           [required by frama-c]
```

That might indicate an issue with OPAM's constraints.

The version number of the Phosphorus release is `20170501`. Anything other than that means you won't get Phosphorus, but an older version. It is not worth continuing: the issue must be fixed beforehand.

Comment: This worked! But I had installed from source! Thanks!